# How to Access Calendar Appointments of Other Users using Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

How can I access other users calendar appointments in MS Outlook to validate if the appointment time created in our application are already taken. We have an account to access MS Graph APIs.

Comment: As per further checking, the other account needs to allow calendar delegation access or it needs to be shared. Is there anyway to access the calendars without delegation and sharing using MS Graph? We prefer this because it's hard to maintain that for each user that we need to have an access, we need to perform delegation setup.

Answer (score 0):

As per further research, MS Graph requires delegation and sharing to enable access to other users' calendar. No other workaround.